# Pull locally with Git Gui?

Tags: git, git-gui

I'm new to Git and using the Windows Gui.

After making several commits, I made an uncommitted change I don't like.

How do I fetch my last local commit and overwrite the working copy with it?

Comment: Which Windows GUI are you using? You have to provide that information.

Comment: I'm using Shawn Pearce et al.'s git-gui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command line, you would have to call `git reset --hard HEAD^` to go back one commit.

So, in your GUI tool, you'll probably have an option called `reset` or something similar. If you're using Github for windows, a similar option is called `revert`.

Although, you should consider that if your commit have been pushed and shared with other devs, you shouldn't use `reset` as this could create trouble with the repo history of your collegue (`revert` command from github GUI would be fine in such a case). But no trouble if it's only local.

**EDIT**

In git-gui as this is the GUI used, you have the option "Revert Changes" under the "Commit" menu. As of more, you also have "Amend Last Commit" in the same submenu, and if you only want to go back to your previous clean state and remove all uncommited changes, you have the "Reset" option in the "Branch" menu.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I don't see a reset or revert option in git-gui .

Comment: Just edited with more detail for git-gui. You probably haven't check the right place because both options are there.